# Exchange Transport Service Won't start

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011, exchange, windows

Initially it was because of a corrupt database file so as I'm not fussed about missing the emails, I removed the files in the `data\queue` folder. When I try to restart the edge transport service, it re-creates the `mail.que` file (and some log files) but still fails to start.

The only event logs I have are:

```
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5485 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000007FEF96C600A) (80131506)
```

followed by

```
Faulting application name: edgetransport.exe, version: 14.2.328.9, time stamp: 0x50b6cee7
Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version: 2.0.50727.5485, time stamp: 0x53a11d6c
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000001a0b39
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
```

These event logs happen 3 times (with some other information logs in between to say this has started etc) then this ends it:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: edgetransport.exe
P2: 14.2.328.9
P3: 50b6cee7
P4: mscorwks.dll
P5: 2.0.50727.5485
P6: 53a11d6c
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000001a0b39
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_edgetransport.ex_ef97ceb937a369a43ba29ff1b801ff682d3aa2f_222a0f7b

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: fdd35af7-709d-11e4-9a66-f46d0463b363
Report Status: 4
```

This is `.wer` description of the issue:

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=130609534363562129
ReportType=2
Consent=1
ReportIdentifier=31aea4e1-70a1-11e4-9a66-f46d0463b363
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=edgetransport.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=14.2.328.9
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=50b6cee7
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=mscorwks.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=2.0.50727.5485
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=53a11d6c
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=00000000001a0b39
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.305.9
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=2057
UI[2]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\edgetransport.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\edgetransport.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.4940_none_88df89932faf0bf6\MSVCR80.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\mscorlib\fe6ac93181b40a571892e14bfb9d65f2\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System\c39e007f266c9c795a5686e8102d3805\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\EdgeTransport\9ca3bab0dd0ca6cc4884de8df3dade44\EdgeTransport.ni.exe
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Core\7f7209284c5ab4a271755c13d2a5cb9e\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\ec0ecdec18b056da9128a7e66d6b5b30\Microsoft.Exchange.Net.ni.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\eadc4546b8313efc0c8c5c86ab76b266\Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.ni.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\ec05206d0f2ed67cd53d00563199773c\Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Common.ni.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Configuration\b3d7d52d8100a364aa006c4c493cec00\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Web\9ca9a1c8e45b27458fddf334f80f3344\System.Web.ni.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Xml\8ef7c8c7d48363669e08791b46f72f8d\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorjit.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\system32\iphlpapi.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\d782a6dd5d44d5b1d16f0a4d0ed00a35\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.ni.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\949df8bc67de28b013d2fbe37b7ea16c\Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ni.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\2dcc78d0f2c41869c8c6d3d7582b28c0\Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ni.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\90f086e37a5e797e91b0376bf23cc33b\Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.ni.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\system32\psapi.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\dsaccessperf.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4959_none_08e45ce1a83d7e3c\MSVCR90.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\EXCHMEM.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\system32\wer.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\ExTrace.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\c734fc703839b8d8473397fb49b9bb2f\Microsoft.Exchange.MessageSecurity.ni.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\1c7ec6c43fbe7fd3dab37ce5827265ea\Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Transport.ni.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\9bc5a53011aabeafd5410e89f4320715\Microsoft.Exchange.Extensibility.Internal.ni.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\6a995f9509d9bde6e981c2353be7893b\Microsoft.Exchange.Common.ni.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\d3350656c7c2ae59c8631cd0da6b4ed5\Microsoft.Exchange.Core.Strings.ni.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\bffef403c48d4bd200475e39b45d6997\Microsoft.Exchange.Isam.Interop.ni.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\5ab9d0109ff779178eef8cb66f3aa7d5\Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ApplicationLogic.ni.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.Isam.Interop.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\ESE.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\eseback2.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4959_none_08e45ce1a83d7e3c\msvcm90.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\system32\crypt32.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\dcf9a4e1186ae2bb10ab72be66115f24\Microsoft.Exchange.Rpc.ni.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.Rpc.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\system32\AUTHZ.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Windows\system32\GPAPI.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\en\Microsoft.Exchange.Core.Strings.resources.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\en\Microsoft.Exchange.Data.resources.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.DirectorySer#\0149d6e4995f152c2d968b70811599ba\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.ni.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.DirectorySer#\74c8d286d487150243ea478f887679c3\System.DirectoryServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\system32\wldap32.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\system32\SECUR32.DLL
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\system32\SSPICLI.DLL
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\system32\pwdssp.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\2e263d75796e404df4580281c4007cf6\Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.ObjectModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\en\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.resources.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\system32\NTDSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\system32\kerberos.DLL
LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\system32\cryptdll.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\system32\bcryptprimitives.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\system32\Netapi32.dll
LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\system32\DSROLE.DLL
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\ebdc3fc1a2b309aea792e983a4f9ba92\Microsoft.Exchange.Compliance.ni.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\Windows\system32\shfolder.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\transportRoles\agents\TrustedMail\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.agent.TrustedMailAgents.dll
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\transportRoles\agents\RmSvc\Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.RmSvcAgent.dll
LoadedModule[106]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\agents\Hygiene\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.Hygiene.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\135b78f7b069eb812c99abd5579356c8\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.AntiSpam.Common.ni.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.ContentFilter.ComInterop.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\system32\SXS.DLL
LoadedModule[111]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.ProtocolAnalysis.DbAccess.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\en\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.ProtocolAnalysis.DbAccess.resources.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\system32\logoncli.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\system32\msv1_0.DLL
LoadedModule[118]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\agents\Prioritization\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.Prioritization.dll
LoadedModule[119]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\agents\Rule\Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.TransportRuleAgent.dll
LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\2a5fb820791700363657e3b53bd0a589\Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.Rules.ni.dll
LoadedModule[121]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\Microsoft.Exchange.#\6cdeda09868ed27d7f670be67965d365\Microsoft.Exchange.MobileDriver.ni.dll
LoadedModule[122]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\transportRoles\agents\Journaling\Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.JournalAgent.dll
LoadedModule[123]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\transportRoles\agents\Redirection\Microsoft.Exchange.MessagingPolicies.RedirectionAgent.dll
LoadedModule[124]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_64\System.Management.A#\9913a8689705b5115c2bfaa9f2444039\System.Management.Automation.ni.dll
LoadedModule[125]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
FriendlyEventName=APPCRASH
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=edgetransport.exe
AppPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\EdgeTransport.exe
ReportDescription=Stopped working
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the exchange instance to service pack 3 sorted this issue out.